# Why is this function marked as noexcept, but can throw?

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is a function from **< mutex >** (MSVSC)

Part of `conditional_variable`:

```
void notify_one() noexcept { // wake up one waiter
        _Check_C_return(_Cnd_signal(_Mycnd()));
    }
```

It's marked as *noexcept*, but `_Check_C_return` can throw(from **< xthreads.h >**):

```
inline int _Check_C_return(int _Res) { // throw exception on failure
    if (_Res != _Thrd_success) {
        _Throw_C_error(_Res);
    }

    return _Res;
}
```

So, I've got 2 questions:

1. Why is it marked as *noexcept*?
2. If it throws in my program, is it my fault?

Comment: Don't think of `noexcept` as "This function won't throw any exceptions," but as, "This function won't throw any exceptions during normal program operation. If it does, we're no longer in normal program operation. Just terminate."

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but could you clarify what version of MSVSC?

Comment: @Chipster ```_MSC_FULL_VER=192428316```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`notify_one`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) is required to be `noexcept` by the language.

If the internal implementation of `notify_one` tries to throw, then this is a bug in the library implementation.  If the exception is thrown, `std::terminate` is required to be called.

However, looking at the headers and source code provided with the compiler, it appears (if I'm reading thru all those macros, typedefs, and inline methods correctly) that the value returned from `_Mycnd()` will be a pointer to an internal class member, which will never be NULL.  The condition will then always be true, so that nothing is ever thrown.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes I got an exception. So VS takes me to that line with unhandled exception

Comment: @mylibh I've double checked my analysis and still don't see where it would actually throw, so there's something I'm missing. What exception is getting thrown?  You may be able to tell the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown (via the "Exception Settings" tab, which may only be available when the debugger is running).  Then report back what the exception is and where it is being thrown from.

Comment: @mylibh Possibly you're calling `notify_one` on a `conditional_variable` that has been deleted or destroyed?

Answer (score 3):

`notify_one` is marked as `noexcept` because the Standard specifies that it must be.

If an uncaught exception is thrown inside a `noexcept` function , then `std::terminate` is called, which aborts the program (and the stack may or may not be unwound).  I can't really answer whether the exception is "your fault" or not, this would depend on details of the library implementation and analyzing under what conditions a `throw` statement might be executed.